# Pass initial condition as an argument to a custom aggregate

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I want to create a function that takes an initial condition as an argument and uses a set of values to compute a final result. In my specific case (has to do with geometry processing in PostGIS), it's important that each member of the set is processed against the current (which might be the initial) state one at a time for keeping the result clean. (I need to deal with sliver and gap issues, and have had a very difficult time doing so any way other than one element at a time.) The processing I need to do is already defined as a function that takes two appropriate arguments (where the first can be the current state and the second can be a value from the set).

So I want something similar to what you would expect is intended by this:

```
SELECT my_func('some initial condition', my_table.some_column) FROM my_table;
```

Aggregates seem like a natural fit for this, but I can't figure out how to get the function to accept an initial state. An iterative approach in PL/pgSQL would be fairly straightforward:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(initial sometype, values sometype[])
  -- Returns, language, etc.
  AS $$
  DECLARE
    current sometype := initial;
    v sometype;
  BEGIN
    FOREACH v IN ARRAY values LOOP
      current := SomeBinaryOperation(current, v);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN current;
  END
  $$
```

But it would require rolling the values up into an array manually:

```
SELECT my_func('some initial condition', ARRAY_AGG(my_table.some_column)) FROM my_table;
```

You can create aggregates with multiple arguments, but the arguments that follow the first one are used as additional arguments to the transition function. I can see no way that one of them could be turned into an initial condition. (At least not without a remarkably hacky function that treats its third argument as an initial condition if the first argument is NULL or similar. And that's only if the aggregate argument can be a constant instead of a column.)

Am I best off just using the PL/pgSQL iterative approach, or is there a way to create an aggregate that accepts its initial condition as an argument? Or is there something I haven't thought of?

I'm on PostgreSQL 9.3 at the moment, but upgrading may be an option if there's new stuff that would help.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "remarkably hacky". Take a look at [`string_agg_transfn`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/b48ecf862b3896631660ee8d38054aded82a4f8b/src/backend/utils/adt/varlena.c#L4309), for example. It uses a null check on the transition state to perform the initialisation, and it selectively ignores its last argument depending on the outcome of this check. Your case seems no different. I say go for it.

Comment: @NickBarnes I would say that situation is a bit different since the delimiter is used every iteration while my "initial state" would be used only once. That said, it does establish some precedence for conditionally doing things with constant arguments. It still feels pretty yucky, though. Thanks. (Side note: I wonder what would happen if you put a column for the delimiter instead of a constant.)

Comment: Here's another way of looking at it: there is no opportunity to inject any logic before the first transition, there is no way to identify a transition as the first one without examining the state, and there is no way to pass in a user-supplied value other than making it an argument. I don't think this leaves you with any alternatives. Maybe a little yucky, but I think adding workarounds to the aggregate creation interface would be worse. And as long as it's all hidden from the caller, I don't think it really matters. (Re column arguments, you'd just get a new value in each transition)